# Is there a way to remove the ttl from all keys in redis?

Tags: redis

I'm wanting to a redis instance to be used for development purposes without any expirations in it. Is there way to remove the ttl from all the keys in the database?

Answer (score 0):

The following command via redis-cli will loop through all the keys in the selected database and call the persist command which removes the ttl:

```
EVAL "for i, name in ipairs(redis.call('KEYS', '*')) do redis.call('persist', name); end" 0
```

Comment: `KEYS` is a dangerous command, which might block Redis for a long time.